# "Given that apartheid fell so recently and..."

Tags: word-usage, sentence-meaning, word-order, sentence-structure

I came across the [following sentence](http://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2015/apr/13/cape-town-remove-cecil-rhodes-statue) but I could not understand its structure and meaning and how the word **given** functions there.

Is it similar to the sentences which begin "having said that"?

> Given that apartheid fell so recently and its legacies survive in
>   huge disparities of wealth, education and land distribution, what is
>   truly surprising is that the monument has survived for so long.

Comment: "Given that" is more or less synonymous with "Since" or "Considering how"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [***given***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/given):

> 5) taken as a premise; assumed; granted   ⇒ "*given that ABC is a right triangle*"

So,

> Given that apartheid fell so recently and its legacies survive in huge disparities of wealth, education and land distribution

is the premise for the rest of the statement

> what is truly surprising is that the monument has survived for so long

You would need to accept the first phrase for the second one to be applicable.

> Given that ELL is a such a great SE community, you will be able to get answers to all your questions here.